# Why is the net flux in a cube surface area zero when the source charge is located outside?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Can some one please explain why a charge located outside a box shaped surface area produces zero net flux? I know this question has been asked many times, but I can't seem to find one that answers my problem with it.

I cannot seem to make sense of this because if the electric field decreases in magnitude with increasing distance from the source, won't the electric field lines leaving the surface have less magnitude than the ones entering it since it is farther from the source due to the surface area having a certain width, which leads to a greater flux inwards than outwards? Thanks﻿ in advance.

Comment: Don't forget about the other surfaces in the calculation, if you trace any one field line that enters the cube, you will see that it also exits the cube even if not by the face directly opposite the side where it entered.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your confusion. The field lines that you see in illustrations of flux do not get *weaker* over time, counterintuitively. The 1/r^2 dropoff of an electric field is not due to the lines getting weaker; it is due to the fact that the electric field is being spread over a wider area as it gets further from the source charge, and thus it is less dense. In other words, that 1/r^2 isn't a property of the field- it's a property of geometry. Each line you see entering a closed surface, like a box, is the same strength when entering as it is when exiting.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I suggest you reconsider the statement: "The 1/r^2 dropoff of an electric field is not due to the lines getting weaker; it is due to the fact that the electric field is being spread over a wider area", which is definitely wrong. It is the nature of the electric field, you can see that in its point-like values without considering any area. The correct argument explaining the 0 flux, is the increase in surface area with distance, at a fixed solid angle.

Comment: @ohneVal Thanks for your reply. I am rather confused, though. For any "stuff" distributed over some spherical shell with radius R, its density over its surface will drop by 1/r^2 as the total surface area grows exponentially. Is this not a fundamental property of a constant value distributed over an increasing spherical surface? And if this geometrical contribution causes a 1/r^2 decrease in density (i.e. field strength in this case), any inherent weakening of the field itself over some distance will result in a decrease faster than 1/r^2.

Comment: Appreciate your input Leo. This taught me something about the inverse square law that I didn't know. Basically what you said makes total sense to me! From what I understand from ohneVal's input, to me, he's basically saying the same thing as you, just in different words.

Answer (score 1):

Just visualize the flux as an incompressible  fluid flow (that's what the word means after all) and where the charge is a magical source of fluid. Now imagine a  box-shaped region in  the fluid. Because the fluid is incompressible the total amount of fluid in the box must  always stay the same. If you have a charge (source) *inside*   of then box then whatever fluid is appearing at the source must flow out of the box: there is a net flux. If the source is *outside* the box then whatever flows in through some sides  of the box must flow out somewhere else. In this case the *net* flux is zero.

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for the flux calculation, there is a scalar product and the angle between the surface normal and the field at each point must be involved. The larger the angle, the smaller the flux.

If the surface is farther, the field is weaker but the angle is also lower. On the whole cube, the flux compensate each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But since it is a cube won't the angle between the surface and the field be zero for the surface entered by the field and the surface exited? Why would the angle change the further the field travels when the exited surface is also flat?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. For say a point charge outside the surface, the field vectors projected increases in angle relative to each other and thus on a flat surface further away, the field lines perpendicular to the surface have less magnitude.

Comment: But what about say if the cubic surface area is lying on a uniform electric field, not a point charge?

Comment: In this last case, the two flux are equal, with opposite signs and the flux is zero.

Comment: How are they equal if the vectors leaving the box has lower magnitude than the ones entering? And since it is a uniform field, the angle shouldn't change the farther the field travels.

Comment: For a single direction field in empty space (no volume charges), of the form $\overrightarrow{E}=E(x)\overrightarrow{{{e}_{x}}}$ , the component $E(x)$cannot depend on $x$ because you have the Gauss law : $\overrightarrow{\nabla }\overrightarrow{E}=0=\frac{\partial E(x)}{\partial x}$

Comment: You had imagined a field that did not check Gauss's theorem and in this case, the flux on a cube would not be zero !

Comment: Sorry but you are right, unfortunately I actually can't make out what you mentioned in the last two comments. Any sources you can recommend to me to understand some of the terms you mentioned? For example you had Gauss law as gradient of E, and I'm also not too sure what you mean by E(x) or E=E(x)ex. I definitely need to review my vector calculus lol. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I live in France and therefore I am not familiar with the school curriculum you follow. There are a lot of good books of electromagnetism (Griffiths for example) but I think that your teachers can advise you much better than me!

Answer (score 0):

If you placed any net charge outside the box (for a uniform electric field), the net flux through it is zero. Why? Because what we mean by a uniform electric field is a series of parallel field lines passing in and out of the box.

Uniform electric fields are generated in capacitor plates. The inverse square law would say that the field lines would diverge and you might think that this creates a non-zero flux, but at appropriate distances (in millimetres probably) that divergence would be minimum and we can imagine those field lines to be *uniform* as they are called.

What I mean by divergence of field lines is literally the *spreading* of theirs.

Comment: Thanks! This was very insightful and made me realize that since a uniform electric field is generated by capacitor plates, then the field lines passing through the surface area inside will not decrease with further distance! Also made me realize that the inverse square law only applies to point charges.

Comment: In fact, it is also true for every other electric field as well. Not just uniform field lines. This is because electric field is only the electric _flux density_ (i.e. the number of field lines $\phi$ passing through an area $A$). It does not matter how they the field lines diverge indicating that the field strength is not the same at both the entry and the exit boundaries.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457691 (I have written an answer to a very similar question yesterday).